# Does a noble have to pay or otherwise maintain the servant they start with?

Tags: followers-and-hirelings, wfrp-4e

In WFRP 4e one of the trappings that a character in the noble path (scion) starts with is a servant.

Does the servant generate money on its own (presumably by the scion's family) and otherwise take care of itself or is the noble in question in charge of paying them as well as finding them a place to stay and meet their other necessities?

Answer (score 6):

## Between adventures, no. During adventures...

Many careers in WFRP fourth edition are linked to organizations, henchmen, retinues and various followers. The question is therefore interesting in many situations, not just the Noble. The Noble is an exception simply because he has a Personal servant among his trappings from level 1 on (Scion). Yet, I don't see why this relationship with the Personal servant should be any different from other "NPC trappings".

### Endeavours

The **Money To Burn** rule (p. 195) specifically addresses the management of money between adventures (emphasis mine):

> After you’ve rolled on the Event Table, you can spend the money earned during your last adventures using the normal rules. Then, after completing your Endeavours, all money held by your character is considered spent. All of it. (...) What happened to it? **It was spent, stolen, drunk, gambled, used for repairs, to pay off debts or taxes, given as a charitable donations or votive offerings, spent on bribes, or used in whatever other way you prefer**. You should concoct the best story for what happens to those funds, as it explains a lot about your character.

So obviously, and unless your character spends time trying to save some coins via the *Banking* Endeavour, he ends up with nothing. But the interesting part is *how* money is spent. Although not explicitly mentioned, paying wages for retainers and servants, necessities of a lavish lifestyle, makes perfect sense. I doubt many GM would add the cost of your servants and henchmen *in addition of the list* of spending habits, as the character would end any downtime period indebted, and as it would make little sense.

However, you can perfectly decide that you do otherwise. Your Noble character may be awfully stingy - and spend liberally silver and gold to achieve an adequate decadent reputation, while his men just try to survive with what is left from the banquet. It's probably the best way of ending up alone (or setting up an NPC revenge at the worst moment) but the point is, the choice is the player character to make.

Therefore, by default, there is no maintenance cost for a Personal servant between adventures.

### While adventuring

On the opposite, there is no rule for wages and henchmen costs while adventuring, and to me that's for a reason: it's up to the player and the GM to decide what happens then. Maybe the adventure is short enough not to bother with such details (wages are not paid daily after all). Maybe the Noble will order his Personal servant to follow him in this dangerous journey as the only way to keep his job, or out of fear or what would happen if he walked away. Maybe a servant will accept the risk of underground exploration with the promise of a share of the treasure. Maybe every "extra" will cost the master a handful of coins because "that's not my duty, m'sir."

Is it the master's responsibility to pay for expenses? Certainly, but only up to a point. A Noble can pay for the meals and a pallet for his Personal servant while travelling, but for the quality your mileage may vary. The Noble is unlikely to provide a comfortable lifestyle, extra alcohol consumption, luxury items or more unless he has a very close relationship with the Personal servant, or is extremely wealthy. Even then, the question of the real ownership (the Noble or the Personal servant carrying the item) is the master's choice, even for a simple suit of leather armor.

A Personal servant is a close NPC because he's always following his master. Other kind of "NPC trappings" - like the Staff of Diplomats of an Ambassador (Envoy level 4) or the Subordinate Interrogators of an Inquisitor (Witch Hunter level 3) - may spend more of their time away, and have a more distant relationship with their master. We can imagine in such situation that they earn money of their own, or receive wages from powerful NPC or organizations, like the King of the distant kingdom the Envoy comes from. But as soon as some NPC follows the leading character along his adventures and obeys his orders, it's expected that the player character assumes the associated expenses.

### Some final remarks

More than a simple trappings, the GM should work with the player the relationship between the Personal servant and his master. It defines much of the way expenses will be managed. Do the Personal servant works out of greed, fear, family loyalty? How well does he know the Noble? For how long has he been serving him or his family? Maybe his sister or uncle works for the Scion's father? Answer to these questions can alter what can be asked from the servant, and how the Scion will care (or not) about his servant.

**The Personal servant can be a PC as well**. It can lead to fun relationships among the player characters, if players indulge in such social play. In that case the details of the work contract between them are left to players themselves. How the master and his servant work together, or how the servant emancipates himself from his master, can lead to memorable story arcs within the group.

If some characters care about their henchmen, others might be annoyed by them, sacrifice them or simply get rid of them. This is not a very good idea. As they are listed as trappings, it means **they are part of the career the character embraces**. A Scion without a Personal servant would therefore look like an impostor, as any self-respecting Noble would never walk alone, dress alone and cook his own food.

If the player characters ends up alone for too long, the GM may decide to apply the penalties listed under **Keeping up appearances** rules (p. 51) as he lacks the proper standing - a Personal servant for a Scion. Note that *Keeping up appearances* rule refers to adventure time, not downtime.

If the master has an awful reputation, he may have trouble recruiting new employees, but will soon understand that keeping a healthy circle of loyal servants is essential for his well-being. Such a character should soon learn the importance of maintaining a good status within the organization/court/family he's part of.